# rollapply for moving average with non-business day

Tags: r, finance, moving-average

I'd like to get MovingAverage in data which have "NA" in the middle of data like below.

```
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2018-07-02"),as.Date("2018-07-14"),by = "days")

A <- c(100,110,120,130,140,NA,NA,150,160,170,180,190,200)
B <- c(200,220,240,260,280,NA,NA,300,320,340,360,380,400)
C <- c(150,160,170,180,190,200,210,NA,NA,220,230,240,250)

dataset <- data.frame(A,B,C)
dataset <- as.xts(dataset, order.by = date)
```

If I use `rollapply` like below to get 3-day MovingAverage...

```
y <- rollapply(dataset, width = 3, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE ))
```

This is not what I want. 
For example, In MovingAverage of A at `"2018-07-09"`, the result is `(NA+NA+150)/1 = 150`. But I want to get `(130+140+150)/3 = 140`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't show screenshots of your data! You had posted your data in a copy&paste-able format just before. Why did you take it down? Also please properly format your code using the editing tools.

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Can you see?

Comment: Yes, I saw your edit. Please include your data in a copy&paste-able format (as text), not as a screenshot.

Comment: I edited again. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The value of `(130+140+150)/3` for `"2018-07-09"` in `A` does *not* correspond to a 3 day rolling average but to a 5 day rolling average.

Comment: I want to get 3-business day moving average.

Comment: NA mean non-business day.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want NAs to stay as NA and otherwise to take the mean of the last 3 non-NAs.

**1)** Take 5 elements at a time and if the last element is NA then return NA; otherwise, remove the NAs and take the mean of the last 3.  Note that this does imply that the first 4 rows will be NA.

```
mean_bus <- function(x) if (is.na(tail(x, 1))) NA else mean(tail(na.omit(x), 3))
y1 <- rollapplyr(dataset, width = 5, mean_bus)
```

**2)** An alternate would be to take the last 3 non-NAs and then overwrite that with NAs in all positions where the input is NA.

```
mean_omit <- function(x) mean(tail(na.omit(x), 3))
y <- rollapplyr(dataset, 5, mean_omit)
y2 <- replace(y, is.na(dataset), NA)

all.equal(y1, y2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**3)** If you prefer to fill in the first 4 rows with partial values then convert to zoo and use the partial= argument of `rollapplyr.zoo`.  `mean_bus` is from (1).

```
y3 <- as.xts(rollapplyr(as.zoo(dataset), 5, mean_bus, partial = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either remove the NAs in each series before you compute the moving average (MA).

Or you use a larger window and keep only the last three values for the MA.

```
y <- rollapply(dataset, width = 5,
               function(x) {mean(tail(x[ !is.na(x) ], 3))})
```